# Empty juli.yyy-MM-dd.log created on Tomcat 6 startup

Tags: tomcat, logging

Everytime Tomcat 6.0.44 startup, there was a empty log file created if this file not exists, with a name like **juli.2015-09-05.log**. There won't be a juli.yyyy-MM-dd.log file of the day without Tomcat startup.

Some explanation about why this log file created? I havn't configured it!

How to get rid of this empty log file?

---

The CLI:

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/koala/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/koala/tomcat6/endorsed -classpath /home/koala/tomcat6/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/koala/tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/home/koala/tomcat6 -Dcatalina.home=/home/koala/tomcat6 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/koala/tomcat6/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

/home/koala/tomcat6/conf/logging.properties:

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINEST
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
```

Comment: Did you find the reason why these juli.*.log files were created? We've some Tomcat instances that exhibit this problem and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you comment out the unnecessary log?
It should be excluded from the "handlers".

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler,     java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

# 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
# 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
# 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
```